# Why does my php while loop block output

Tags: php

I have php code like this:

```
<?php

While (1)echo "hello";
```

The server is outputing a chunk of data instead of progressively outputting each 'hello'

Comment: Google "php server push" to learn how to do real-time output from PHP.

Answer (score 4):

By default, PHP output is not sent to the browser while the script executes. Nothing gets sent to the browser until the script finishes. Since your loop never ends, the script never exits, so nothing shows in the browser.

Comment: He can use `ob_flush` to send the buffer content to the browser immediately.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH that's a bit of a hit-or-miss approach it wont always work

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't always work it waits until the buffer is full and sends all the data at one time